# SQL Insert new years into the calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, calendar, sqldatatypes

I am completely new to SQL still have been asked to help because there is no one else to do it.

Among other stuff that was figured out I can't understand how add additional year to the Calendar table in the SQL Server database.

The table was set for 8 years, starting at Jan.2013 and ending at this December. Is it possible to prolong before this date will come?

The only syntax I've came up with is:

```
INSERT INTO dim.calendar [ (PK, date, year...) ] 
VALUES (20210101, 2021-01-01, 2021 ...)
```

But I'm pretty sure that there should be another, fastest way by cycling params of the dates inside the year.

Thank you for any help

[image: information scheme]

[image: table itself]

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to generate such data is with a Tally. This should be more than enough to get you on the right path:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20000101',
        @EndDate date = '20201231';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)+1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5), --100,000 days, more than enough, but add more cross joins to N for more
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate) AS CalendarDate
    FROM Tally T)
--INSERT INTO dbo.CalendarTable
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),D.CalendarDate,112) AS PK,
       D.CalendarDate,
       DATEPART(YEAR, D.CalendarDate) AS CalendarYear,
       DATEPART(MONTH, D.CalendarDate) AS CalendarMonth,
       DATEPART(DAY, D.CalendarDate) AS CalendarDay
FROM Dates D;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
WITH DatesTable AS
(SELECT CAST('19000101' as date) AS [date], year('19000101') [year], MONTH('19000101') [month], DAY('19000101') [day] 
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]), year(DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])) year, MONTH(DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])) month, DAY(DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])) day 
FROM DatesTable
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '20300101'
)
SELECT * into dim.calendar FROM DatesTable
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

19000101 is a start date
20300101 is a end date

Comment: This is, however, unlikely to be much faster than a `WHILE`, if at all. This suffers the same RBAR problems. [Speed Test: rCTE vs Tally](https://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/)